# What's the difference between 受到 and 产生 when used with 影响, 兴趣, etc

Tags: usage, difference

So, I'm struggling to see the difference between these two verb-noun collocations.
In your opinion, is there are a difference between:

- 受到影响 and 产生影响 to (be) influenced
- 受到兴趣 and 产生兴趣 to (become) interested??

I feel like there should be a difference, but I'm at a loss to see what it could be... maybe active/passive?!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... 受到 means "to be the recipient of an action" or "to receive" or just passive, 產生 means "to produce" or "to bring into being". They are very different words, I don't see the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

受到影响 = to be influenced

受到A的影响 = to be influenced by A

产生影响 = to have an influence

对A产生影响 = to have an influence on A

受到兴趣: no such expression

产生兴趣 = to become interested

对A产生兴趣 = to become interested in A

Comment: Ah brilliant. Yes, I can see that these are inherently different verbs now - thanks for the clarification :-)